# Fonts are not found (404) on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

After deploying to heroku, the fonts get lost, meaning they are not found when a page loads.

```
#application.ru

config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
```

This is what was suggested on the forums. But that doesn't work. There are no error during deploying to heroku.

What else can I do?

**/app/assets/stylesheets/_fonts.css.scss**

```
#..............................

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Verb Extra Bold';
    src: asset-url('verbextrabold-webfont.eot');
    src: asset-url('verbextrabold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         asset-url('verbextrabold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         asset-url('verbextrabold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         asset-url('verbextrabold-webfont.svg#verbextrabold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

#..............................
```

Comment: How do you link to the fonts from your stylesheets? You shouldn't even have to add it to the assets load paths to get it to work when they're in app/assets/fonts.

Comment: Can you try heroku run rake assets:precompile ?

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but try changing `asset-url` to `font-url`. Try precompiling the assets on your local machine to see if the fonts also get included by running `ENV=production rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: @fivedigit, I did both, not sure what exactly helped me but that helped, thanks.

Comment: I fixed this by moving the fonts from the vendor/assets folder to the root assets folder. Rails 4 and Heroku. Works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your fonts are in `app/assets/fonts`, you shouldn't have to add them to the load path, so you can remove the two lines from your `application.rb`.

Try changing `asset-url` to `font-url` in your stylesheet.

You can check if precompiling works locally by running `ENV=production rake assets:precompile` in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Put *woff*, *eot*, *svg* and *ttf* files in **app/assets/fonts**
and font_name.**scss** in **app/assets/stylesheets** folder

Don't forget the **.scss** extension and **asset_path** helper

```
font-url( asset_path('file.woff')) format('woff')
```

And this in assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
```

#### Pe-icon-7-stroke.css example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pe-icon-7-stroke';
    src:url(asset_path('Pe-icon-7-stroke.eot?-2irksn'));
    src:url( asset_path('Pe-icon-7-stroke.eot?#iefix-2irksn')) format('embedded-opentype'),
        font-url( asset_path('Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff?-2irksn')) format('woff'),
        font-url(asset_path('Pe-icon-7-stroke.ttf?-2irksn')) format('truetype'),
        font-url(asset_path('Pe-icon-7-stroke.svg?-2irksn#Pe-icon-7-stroke')) format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: No problem @MartinZabel. Edited.

Comment: thank you so much, changing my css file to .scss and url => font-url made it.